# How to fix "URL rewrite vulnerability" in Laravel version 5.2.45

Tags: security, laravel-5

I am getting the below security warning in the scan report with a laravel project built in version  5.2.45.

> URL rewrite vulnerability

Below is the description.

> It was identified that this application supports the legacy headers X-Original-URL and/or X-Rewrite-URL.Support for these headers lets users override the path in the request URL via the X-Original-URL or X-Rewrite-URL HTTP request header and allows a user to access one URL but have web application return a different one which can bypass restrictions on higher level caches and web servers. Many web frameworks such as Symfony 2.7.0 to 2.7.48, 2.8.0 to 2.8.43, 3.3.0 to 3.3.17, 3.4.0 to 3.4.13, 4.0.0 to 4.0.13 and 4.1.0 to 4.1.2 , zend-diactoros up to 1.8.4, zend-http up to 2.8.1, zend-feed up to 2.10.3 are affected by this security issue.

Any suggestions on how to fix this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "composer update" after setting the new value in composer.json?

```
  "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
```

As documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

Comment: It was still giving the same warning even after Upgrade.

Comment: What type of warning? Did you try upgrading several versions on a local setup?

Answer (score 0):

Got the Fix. Added below code to the root htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  RequestHeader unset X-Original-URL
  RequestHeader unset X-Rewrite-URL
</IfModule>
```